# how to integration test email body in a Grails Service that uses the Mail plugin

Tags: grails, mocking, integration-testing

I am attempting to write integration tests for a Grails service that does, among other things, send email via the excellent [Mail Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail).  I can disable the actual sending of email via configuration, which is great, but I would like to verify that the parameters are correct body is being rendered correctly, or at very least that the method has been called when I expect.  As per the documentation, the full path to GSP for the body must be supplied.

As part my test I'd like to do something like this - is there a way to access the email body and other parameters programmatically after sending?

```
sendMail {
  to myemailparams.to
  subject myemailparams.subject
  body( view:"/emailviews/someemailview", 
      model:[contentparam: myemailparams.somecontentvalue)
}

//verify correct sending to and subject parameters, and that body contains correct contentvalue
//or at least that the method has been called (Mock it out?)
```

Note I realize that I can encapsulate the testing of the email body rendering into a separate isolated test that doesn't involve the mail plugin.  But the purpose of this integration test is to ensure a lot of things, including the email send, happen correctly upon call to the service method.  I would even be satisfied with an answer that describes how to mock the service, and a check that verifies 'sendMail' has been called when expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the sendMail method using [metaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses) and then do some checking to ensure that sendMail was called:

```
void testSendMail() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
    def sendMailCalled = false
    myClass.metaClass.sendMail = { Closure c->
       sendMailCalled = true
    }

    myClass.functionThatCallsSendMail()
    assert sendMailCalled
}
```

Comment: That's very handy - I didn't think about a variable in the closure like that being visible outside the closure to my test.  Works great.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how I assert things that were sent to MailService:

```
def setup(){
    mailParams = [:]
    mockMailService.ignore.sendMail{ callable ->
        messageBuilder = new MailMessageBuilder(null, new ConfigObject())
        messageBuilder.metaClass.body = { Map params ->
            mailParams.body = params
        }
        messageBuilder.metaClass.async = { Boolean param ->
            mailParams.async = param
        }
        messageBuilder.metaClass.to = { String param ->
            mailParams.to = param
        }
        messageBuilder.metaClass.subject = { String param ->
            mailParams.subject = param
        }
        callable.delegate = messageBuilder
        callable.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        callable.call()
    }
    service.mailService = mockMailService.proxyInstance()
}
```

Then, In my test, after executing the method that sends mail, I assert this way (Spock syntax for assertions):

```
    then:
        mailParams.to == 'test@test.com'
        mailParams.async == true
        mailParams.subject == 'fnuser.billingEmail.subject{}en'
        mailParams.body.view == '/mailtemplates/setBillingEmail'
        mailParams.body.model.destinationUrl == "myDestinationUrl"
        mailParams.body.model.logoUrl == 'myUrl/templatelogo.png'
        mailParams.body.model.locale == Locale.ENGLISH
```